# 'Could not index' Error while deploying project to JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jsf-2, jboss7.x

I have a Spring 3 + maven + JSF 2.0 + primefaces project. When I deploy onto Jboss 7.1.1 and run the server all in Eclipse, during start up a lot of Warning messages are displayed such as the following:

```
12:24:28,262 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015852: Could not index class com/sun/faces/context/FacesContextImpl$ComponentMessagesIterator.class at /Users/bonski/Google Drive/MyProject/server/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/SportPack.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.1.6.jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:31) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:459) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:242) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:178) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:152) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.verifyMagic(Indexer.java:387) [jandex-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:630) [jandex-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:77) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
```

At the end I have the following ERROR:

```
12:24:28,943 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SportPack.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SportPack.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "SportPack.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37] Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to get manifest for deployment "/Users/bonski/Google Drive/MyProject/server/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/SportPack.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.1.6.jar"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:73) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more  
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:31) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:459) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:242) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill(Manifest.java:422) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:356) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:390) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:359) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:180) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:50) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.readManifest(VFSUtils.java:216)
at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.getManifest(VFSUtils.java:199)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:69) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 6 more
```

This is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sportPack.app</groupId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>sp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.5.1-Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF library -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- MySQL Java Connector library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>            

    <!-- Log4j library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<artifactId>sp</artifactId>
```

.

Comment: A JSF version is provided with JBoss. You can put `<scope>provided</scope>` for JSF dependency.

Comment: To use the exact version add `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0.Beta1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

`

Comment: have you found solution for this problem?

Comment: So many things in Java and spring  world moved since this post. Don't use Jboss with Spring look into spring boot and instead of using JSF in spring try thymeleaf.